# long-index arrays in python

Tags: python

I'm attempting to shorten the memory footprint of 10B sequential integers by referencing them as indexes in a boolean array. In other words, I need to create an array of 10,000,000,000 elements, but that's well into the "Long" range. When I try to reference an array index greater than sys.maxint the array blows up:

```
x = [False] * 10000000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    x = [0] * 10000000000
OverflowError: cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer
```

Anything I can do? I can't seem to find anyone on the net having this problem... Presumably the answer is "python can't handle arrays bigger than 2B."

Comment: Wow, seriously? Even if you could do that, such an array is unlikely to fit in even a 64 GB machine. I would suggest a different approach.

Comment: a boolean is one bit. 10bil bits = 1.25 megabytes.

Comment: (please correct my assumption if I'm wrong!)

Comment: In Python, True and False are objects.  Each True or each False will cost you one *reference* in terms of memory space.  So, basically, you're looking at 10 billion references, depends on the pointer size of your machine.

Comment: You're wrong.  A list of bools consumes more space than len(lst) bits.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I meant GB not MB. And OK, thanks for the clarification on True/False. Sounds like I'm out of luck on my implementation. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a 32-bit address space, any language is going to be struggling to be able to address such an array. Then there's the problem of how much real memory you have on your computer.

If you want 10B array elements, each element representing either true or false, use an array.array('I', ...) ...

```
container = array.array('I', [0]) * ((10000000000 + 31) // 32)
```

Then you can set and clear bits using the usual masking and shifting operations.

**Alternative:**

If only a small number of elements are true, or only a small number of elements are false, you could use a set for the best memory saving, or a dict for programming convenience.

Comment: +1: Set of True elements is often *much* more efficient than the "giant array of bits" solution.

Answer (score 4):

The [bitarray](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) package looks like it might be another useful option.

Answer (score 3):

A dense bit vector is plausible but it won't be optimal unless you know you won't have more than about `10**10` elements, all clustered near each other, with a reasonably randomized distribution.  If you have a different distribution, then a different structure will be better.

For instance, if you know that in that range, [0,10**10), only a few members are present, use a `set()`, or if the reverse is true, with nearly every element present except for a fraction, use a negated set, ie `element not in mySet`.

If the elements tend to cluster around small ranges, you could use a run length encoding, something like `[xrange(0,10),xrange(10,15),xrange(15,100)]`, which you lookup into by bisecting until you find a matching range, and if the index is even, then the element is in the set.  inserts and removals involve shuffling the ranges a bit.

If your distribution really is dense, but you need a little more than what fits in memory (seems to be typical in practice) then you can manage memory by using `mmap` and wrapping the mapped file with an adaptor that uses a similar mechanism to the suggested `array('I')` solution already suggested.

To get an idea of just how compressible you can possibly get, try building a plain file with a reasonable corpus of data in packed form and then apply a general compression algorithm (such as gzip) to see how much reduction you see.  If there is much reduction, then you can probably use some sort of space optimization in your code as well.

Answer (score 2):

> 10B booleans (1.25MB of memory, assuming Python is sane)

I think you have your arithmetic wrong -- stored supercompactly, 10B booleans would be 1.25 **GIGA**, _not__ **MEGA**, bytes.

A list takes at least 4 bytes per item, so you'd need 40GB to do it the way you want.

You can store an **array** (see the `array` module in the standard library) in much less memory than that, so it might possibly fit.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for very large bit arrays would be to use [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com). It uses a `bytearray` (or `array.array` on older Python versions) to store the data but its interface is just an array of bits. For your case you could use:

```
>>> from bitstring import BitString
>>> s = BitString(10000000000)         # zero initialised
>>> s.set([9, 999999999, 253])         # set 3 bits to '1'
>>> s[66] = True                       # set another bit
>>> s.allset([9, 66])                  # check if bits are set to '1'
True
```

I think it's preferable to doing all the bit masking and shifting yourself!

Answer (score 0):

From googling around some , e.g. [PEP 353](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5/whatsnew/pep-353.html) (assuming I'm understanding it) and [this exchange](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-January/532801.html) it looks like the real issue is probably platform/system dependent.  Do you have enough memory to handle 10,000,000,000 entries?

Comment: I do not have room for 10B integers (which would be 40gigs of memory), but I certainly have room for 10B booleans (1.25MB of memory, assuming Python is sane)

Comment: How are you going to fit 10 billion bools into 10 million bits?